# Magento 2.1.8: How to get Name on Card for my Payment Module

Tags: payment-gateway, magento-2.1.8, credit-card

I'm trying to populate credit card details form from Magento/Payment module. This module doesn't show me Name on Card. How do I populate this field?

Comment: What do you mean by "Name on Card"? Type of credit card or something else?

Comment: Nope, I meant card holder's name. I'm trying to override Magento Payments module. The Magento unit test's shows cc_owner. But I could not locate text box to enter card holder's name.

Comment: The `cc_owner` field is not used by Magento built-in payment methods. `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc` deprecated starting from 2.1.0 release.